# Task/async Lambda on sub list that will call another method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I have a requirement that wants me to replace a value (`StatusName`) that is a field (`ChildItems`) in a list that is a field in another list (`ParentItems`).  I haven't worked a lot with Async / Await so I'm sure I'm not doing this correctly

Here is an example of what I'm trying:

```
public class parentItem {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public List<childItem> ChildItems {get;set;}
}

public class childItem {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string StatusId {get;set;}
    public string StatusName {get;set;}
}

// Populate parent in list.
List<parentItem> parents = new List<parentItem>();
//populate....
```

We have a data call that will populate these elements in an async await method.  I was hoping to do a simple lambda expression that will call another method that will change the value of the status

Kind of like this:

```
// lambda I was hoping to try
parents = parents.Select((par) => {
   par.ChildItems = par.ChildItems.Select((sub) => {
      sub.StatusName = await ChangeChildStatusName(sub.StatusId);
   }).ToList();
   return par;
});

public async Task<string> ChangeChildStatusName(int statusId) {
    // code.
}
```

In this method (`ChangeChildStatusName`) there is a database call getting other information that is needed.  I'm pretty sure there is a different approach for something like this, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution that fits this scenario.

Comment: `Select` transforms each item in a sequence into another item.  It doesn't just execute some code on each item in a sequence.  You use a `foreach` for that. The code wouldn't work even if you were doing everything synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to pay attention to your types. The result of your inner `Select` (after you add a `return sub;`) is a `List<Task<childItem>>`, which you can use with `await Task.WhenAll(..)` to (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete. Similarly, your parent tasks can use the same technique:

```
var parentTasks = parents.Select(async (par) => {
 var childTasks = par.ChildItems.Select(async (sub) => {
   sub.StatusName = await ChangeChildStatusName(sub.StatusId);
   return sub;
 });
 par.ChildItems = (await Task.WhenAll(childTasks)).ToList();
 return par;
});
parents = (await Task.WhenAll(parentTasks)).ToList();
```

However, in your particular case (accessing a database), you can probably only do one database call at a time anyway, so you should replace your nested `Select`s with nested `foreach`s:

```
foreach (var par in parents)
  foreach (var sub in par.ChildItems)
    sub.StatusName = await ChangeChildStatusName(sub.StatusId);
```